# Retrieve custom user's profile image

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfuser

I am having an issue retrieving the profile image for the user who leaves a comment. Here's the code I'm using

```
HTKSampleTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"commentReuseID"];
PFObject *comment = [comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.commentLabel.text = [comment objectForKey:@"text"];

NSDateFormatter* formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString* uploaded = [formatter stringFromDate:comment.createdAt];

cell.timeLabel.text = uploaded;

cell.titleLabel.text = [comment objectForKey:@"author"];


[cell.samImageView loadInBackground];


PFUser *currentUses = [comment objectForKey:@"author"];

[currentUses fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
   NSString *userphoto = [object objectForKey:@"image"];
    NSLog(@"%@", userphoto);

}];
```

When I use an NSLog, currentUses returns the user's username as I save it my posts class as "Author."

This is the error I get:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f4d670'

The query above does have: [query includeKey:@"user"];

Comment: try once in outside the tableview and check you get the same error or not

Comment: The value returned by code [comment objectForKey:@"author"] looks like NSString as you are setting cell.titleLabel.text = [comment objectForKey:@"author"]; Later you are setting PFUser *currentUses = [comment objectForKey:@"author"] which is NSString not PFUser.

Answer (score 2):

The value returned by [comment objectForKey:@"author"] is NSString not PFUser. So you are getting the exception.

Comment: You're right, it is a string. I'm trying to get the user with the string's details. When I use [PFUser currentuser], all the photos are of the user logged in as opposed to photos of the commenters!

Comment: You can get the PFUser using the username                                     PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:@"actualUsername"];
PFUser *user = (PFUser *)[query getFirstObject];

Comment: It worked! It worked! It worked!  Thank you so much!